# Double Clicking Highlighting

Tags: eclipse, highlighting

In Notepad++ if you double click a word to highlight it, all the occurrences of the word in the file are also highlighted, a feature that is quite handy for finding where variables are declared/used.

Does the eclipse editor have this functionality? :) If so, how can I turn it on?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For the Eclipse Java editor, you can go to Window->Preferences in the menu, then Java->Editor->Mark Occurrences in the options tree and check off anything you want highlighted in this way.

Note that the editor understands Java scoping rules, so if you have 2 local variables with the same name in two different functions, it will only highlight within the current function.

Comment: I don't know that there is a general purpose word-highlighter built in (i.e. ships with a default download package) to Eclipse.  You'll probably have to find a plugin.  There are most certainly equivalents out there for other programming languages.  Try searching http://marketplace.eclipse.org/.

Comment: Superb, resolved it in no time, The right link and thanks for the answer Tom

Comment: Good question, Great answer.

Answer (score 6):

I found a plugin called eclipse-glance that searches like notepad++ but without double-clicking

http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-glance/

Comment: This seems to be the closest behavior to Notepad++. I mapped one of my extra mouse buttons to the "Ctrl+Alt+F" combination to more quickly use this plugin. Still not quite as convenient as Notepad++.

Comment: eclipse update site referred while installing from above said link doesn't work now. follow workaround mentioned in [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39357954/i-am-not-able-to-install-glance-plugin-for-eclipse-from-market-place)

Answer (score 5):

Closest to original what I have found is <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

For activate double click hightlighting in Eclipse:

[activate double click hightlighting in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNEmy.jpg)

For change color of double click hightlighting in Eclipse:

[change color of double click hightlighting in Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35efw.jpg)