# I am not able to install Glance plugin for Eclipse from market place.

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am not able to install Glance plugin for Eclipse from market place. 
It is throwing up error.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due shutdown of google code. Ref https://github.com/ystrot/glance/issues/34

You can use below 2 links to update (refer workaround solution ASON)

i used --> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cypher256/glance/master/releng/com.xored.glance-updatesite/site.xml

https://dl.bintray.com/ujhelyiz/generic/glance/1.1.2/repository/

I was able to install recently and BUT!!! link can be moved any time.

[image]